# Is there a way to format strings in MiniZinc?

Tags: minizinc

Is there a way to format MiniZinc output to create, for example, tables in which some of the entries are strings, whose size is determined during the computation?

As a test case I tried to run

```
output ["\(length(show(1234)))"];
```

but got an error message that said

```
no function or predicate with this signature found: `length(string)'
```

UPDATE: I'm teaching about using MiniZinc to do planning problems. Here are two examples: [Wolf-Goal-Cabbage](https://drive.google.com/file/https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cpre3SO4Wi5AviIdg4ppvklE5bC2SFOm/view?usp=sharingd/1cpre3SO4Wi5AviIdg4ppvklE5bC2SFOm/view?usp=sharing) and [N-Jugs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yP83yN2Lg1N-OA62N5FL80CVHCkNB55c/view?usp=sharing). The output of each is formatted.

Answer (score 1):

MiniZinc supports `string_length` so this works:

```
output ["\(string_length(show(1234)))"];
```

There is support for quite a few string functions for formatting, e.g. `show_int`, `format` etc, see https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.2/en/lib-builtins.html?highlight=string#string-operations

Comment: Thanks. I knew about show_int, etc. But there wasn't a show_string. I tried len(<some string>), but that didn't work. I didn't know there was a string_length function! That's what I needed.

Comment: By the way, I'm considering taking your 15-puzzle code and adding a manhattan distance heuristic. Have you already considered that?

Comment: @RussAbbott I haven't modelled the MiniZinc version of the 15 puzzle with Manhattan distance.